# ActionScript , adobe flash

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash

I have a question. I'm beginner so...

I'm creating website on flash and i have 5 pages and 5 buttons(menu buttons) and I need to use menu so I wrote this code but aobe flash writes error 1120, whats a problem?;s

thisi is code

```
{stop();
function projectsButton_clicked (e:MouseEvent) :void {
gotoAndStop("projects");
}

function galleryButton_clicked (e:MouseEvent) :void {
gotoAndStop("gallery");
}

function videosButton_clicked (e:MouseEvent) :void {
gotoAndStop("videos");
}

function backstageButton_clicked (e:MouseEvent) :void {
gotoAndStop("backstage");
}

function pricelistButton_clicked (e:MouseEvent) :void {
gotoAndStop("pricelist");
}

function contactButton_clicked (e:MouseEvent) :void {
gotoAndStop("contact");
}


projectsButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, projectsButton_clicked);
galleryButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, galleryButton_clicked);
videosButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, videosButton_clicked);
backstageButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backstageButton_clicked);
pricelistButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pricelistButton_clicked);
contactButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, contactButton_clicked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a couple of things wrong in your code:

1. The useless braces at the beginning and end of the program { }, but I don't think that affects much.
2. If you're using scenes, this is how gotoAndStop should be used: `gotoAndStop(frame, "Scene name");` , unless they're all frames of a movieclip, in that case you should just use the frame number. Here you go: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001310.html
3. Those were just notes since those might cause errors later, the most likely cause of your error is that one or a couple of buttons mentioned in the code (projectsButton, galleryButton, videosButton, etc...) don't actually exist, they either aren't on the stage or when you were naming them on the stage you misspelled one/some of them. I think you should double check all their instance names.

That's all I can think of, best of luck with your website! ^^

Comment: sorry can u give me an example of frame+ scene number how to write correct with my code?  all buttons are corrects:3

Comment: Sure, if you had a scene named "Scene 2" for example, use `gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2")` Where 1 is the first frame of the scene, and "Scene 2" is the scene you want to go to. PS: If you want to manage scenes, use Shift+F2

Comment: http://s020.radikal.ru/i716/1407/1d/dc3d0681f921.jpg that's a screenshot what i have:s

Comment: Ah, you're trying to move between layers, but you can't; layer's are just for putting something infront of something else: to use `gotoAndStop`, you have to use Scenes: Add a new scene with the button and name each scene what you like (For example, "Gallery", "Videos", etc...) Then you can use `gotoAndStop(1, "Videos");` for example.

Comment: so i'm creating new scenes for all pages of my site, yeap?:s and for future i need to add image gallery  on this pages and lightbox on button click , I'mgoing on a right way with scenes yeap? or I'm constructing wrong?:d O man sorry for hundred of questions:D

Comment: No problem at all, this site is made to answer your questions! And yes, for each page you'll need to make a new scene. Yep, you're going the right way, just make sure it's 1 page per scene. Good luck with your website :D